# take all lines between two pattern by Regex

Tags: python, regex

I used

```
(?<=<li>)..(?=</li>)
```

for only ONE LINE like this:
`pattern1 Everything pattern2`
but it not work for multiple lines!
how can take everything and all lines(1,2,3,4,5) from like this:
(spaces are't necessary)

```
<pre>
pattern1
line1
   line2
      line3
   line4
line5
pattern2
</pre>
```

Comment: This is really vague. Are you using a single regular expression to recognize that start and the end? A separate regular expression for each?

Comment: Please provide a minimal functional example

Comment: Do not use regexes to parse HTML/XML, use a specialized parser instead. This will save you a lot of trouble and pitfalls.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML or XML. For example see [**html.parser**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) from the standard library or [**lxml**](https://lxml.de/).

Comment: thank you. can I use parser for page source? I used requests.get(url)

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/QqlKD4/1) what you looking for?

Comment: in many tutorials you can see how to use `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` with source from `requests.get(url)`

Comment: if you really want to use regex then you may need special option (probably `re.MULTILINE` or `re.DOTALL`) to run multiline.

Comment: you may need `(.*)` instead of `..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many lines you may need option `re.DOTALL` and/or `re.MULTILINE`

```
text = '''<pre>
pattern1
line1
   line2
      line3
   line4
line5
pattern2
</pre>'''

import re

result = re.findall('pattern1(.*)pattern2', text, re.DOTALL)

print('len:', len(result))
print(result[0].strip())
```

Result:

```
len: 1

line1
   line2
      line3
   line4
line5
```